# Cloud-init -- Network config is getting overridden during subsequent boots

Tags: networking, openstack, kvm-virtualization, cloud, cloud-init

How can I make cloud init to run on first boot only?
On my lab, its overriding all networking changes that I have done manually on next boot.

I am passing my network information in meta-data, using `NoCloud` data source (ON KVM guest). Like below:

```
---------meta-data file-------------

instance-id: vault
network-interfaces: 
   auto eth0
   iface eth1 inet static
   address 11.11.0.20
   netmask 255.255.255.0

   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
local-hostname: controller
---------------------------------
```

This method of configuring network is *Network Configuration ENI* in terms of cloud-init.

I tried disabling cloud-init but it's not working.

```
@new-tvault-node:~# cat /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
network: {config: disabled}
```

Using following cloud init package on ubuntu trusty:

```
root@new-tvault-node:~# dpkg-query --show cloud-init
cloud-init      0.7.5-0ubuntu1.18
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get `cloud-init` out of the way and to _really_ make it disabled after adding the value to `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg`?